# How do I use hashing and pickle to save/load objects

Tags: python, pickle, random-access

So I am following a guide in a book about working with random files and have the following code for saving some objects

```
import pickle
from carRec import carRec

cars = [carRec(1, "Ford", "Escort"), carRec(2, "Ford", "Focus"), carRec(3, "Ford", "Mustang")]

#output to carsFile
carFile = open("carsRand.dat", "wb")

for i in range(0,3):
   address = hash(cars[i].vehicleID)
   carFile.seek(address)
   pickle.dump(cars[i], carFile)

carFile.close()
```

And then for loading the data

```
import pickle
from carRec import carRec

carFile = open("cars.dat", "rb")
cars = []
counter = 1

try:
    while True:
        location = hash(counter)
        carFile.seek(location)
        cars.append(pickle.load(carFile))
        counter += 1
except EOFError:
    print("done")

carFile.close()
```

The problem is, when I try to reload the data I get the following error

```
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, ''.
```

Having a quick look inside the dat file makes me think that the writing of the data isnt working properly. I believe that when using the hash and seek functions to identify where to write too/read from, you need to allow for the size of the record in bytes. If this is the case, how do I a) ensure all records are the same size and b) find out the size of a single record?

Answer (score 2):

The issue with this code is that the car objects overwrite previously written car objects when written. This can be fixed by directly pickling the list:

```
import pickle
with open("cars.dat", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(cars, f)
```

This can then be loaded with:

```
with open("cars.dat", "rb") as f:
    cars = pickle.load(f)
```

If you absolutely must pickle the objects separately, you can determine the pickled size of an object with `len(pickle.dumps(obj, -1))`

Additionally, have you considered using the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module? It is the easiest way to persist simple python objects to a file.

**EDIT**: The easiest way to ensure that the records are the same size is to not use pickle. You can, however, store the size of the record alongside the record:

```
import pickle
import struct

with open("cars.dat", "wb") as f:
    for car in cars:
        size = len(pickle.dumps(car, -1))
        f.write(struct.pack("<I", size))
        pickle.dump(car, f)
```

This code stores 4 bytes worth of length information before each record. This length data can then be loaded with `struct.unpack("<I", f.read(4))[0]`

You could then also store the offsets of each (length, data) pair at the beginning of the file, to allow reading the n-th record without traversing through all the previous records.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. So the next problem is that all records are of different sizes. What would be the 'best' way to pack the record so all records are of the same size?

Comment: OK, so just as a test I tried the following,

    `myLen = len(pickle.dumps(cars[i], -1))
    print("original length is", myLen)
    
    if myLen < 200:
        extraSpace = 200 - myLen
         cars[i].packingSpace = "" * extraSpace
        print("extra space is", extraSpace)

    myLen = len(pickle.dumps(cars[i], -1))
    print("new length is",myLen)`

But the length is the same each time. I fear I am not understanding the use of the pickle library correctly :-(

Comment: OK, that could work, try `cars[i].packingSpace = " " * extraSpace` However, this approach has some limitations; notably, cars with makes/models with a total name over 196 or so will corrupt the entire data file, or, worse, open your application up to RCE from specially crafted data. Quite frankly, if you want fixed-width storage, create a data type without strings. If you ever store a string, you also need to store the length, and, oops, your record is no longer fixed length. A record full of ints will always have the same size, not so for a record with even one string. Terse - comment length